# Cuts in recursion of Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog myself and recently came across a piece of notes:-

> Example: nth/3
>
> - for example, to find the nth element of a list we could use

```
    nth([X|_],0,X). 

    nth([_|L],N,X) :- N1 is N - 1, nth(L,N1,X).
```

> - the 0th element of a list is the head of the list (first clause), otherwise 
>     we take the n-1th element of the tail of the list (second clause).
> - once we have found the nth element, we can’t find any more by backtracking.

```
 nth([X|_],0,X). 
 nth([_|L],N,X) :- N1 is N - 1, !, nth(L,N1,X).
```

> - adding a cut makes this clear and may be necessary for tail recursion 
>     optimisation.

However, when I use the trace function in Prolog, I found out that the calling sequences of these 2 pieces of codes are exactly the same.

Should I put the ! mark as follows instead?

```
 nth([X|_],0,X) :- !. 
 nth([_|L],N,X) :- N1 is N - 1, nth(L,N1,X).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cut in the second clause is redundant as there are no more clauses and the goal before it (the `is/2` call) is deterministic. I also don't think that the cut plays any role on tail recursion optimization (which basically requires that you recursive call be the last goal in the clause body).

However, before worrying about cut placement, you should check what happens if you call the `nth/3` predicate in a mode other than `nth(+,+,-)`. For example, what happens in mode `nth(+,+,+)`, i.e. when you call the predicate with all arguments instantiated, *but* the element is not in the list? Hint: moving the cut to the first clause will not solve the problem.

Comment: Yup I can see that in `nth(+,+,+)` putting a cut in the first statement is useless. Here is what I coded to try solving the problem: `nth([X|_],0,X).
nth([_|L],N,X) :- N>0, N1 is N - 1, nth(L,N1,X).`

Comment: basically I just added the constraint `N>0`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. A good followup exercise would be try to define a `nth/3` predicate that works for any mode. Btw, this functionality is usually provided in libraries using the names `nth0/3` (counting from zero) and `nth1/3 (counting from one). The name `nth/3` is deprecated to avoid ambiguity if you're counting from zero or from one.